# Why is javascript executing when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am writing a site using JSP.  I have included a code snippet below.

The problem I'm having is that every time the page loads the `addBookmark()` method inside of the javascript is executed but I do not see the alert.  When I press the button, I see the alert but the `addBookmark()` method is not called.  What is causing this strange behavior?

```
<% User user = new User() %>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function add()
   {
      <% user.addBookmark(); %>                               
      alert("addBookmark");
   }
</script>

<button type="button" style="float: right" onclick="add()">Bookmark</button>
```

Thanks is advance!

Comment: Maybe you should post the generated file (i.e. what your browser sees).

Comment: What is this `user` object that you're trying to trigger `addBookmark()` on? Per @Gabe, post what your browser renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because JSP doesn't communicate directly with the browser, nor does it have any knowledge of what the browser does with the page and what the user does. It's just a simple interpreter that walks through your code and looks for `<%`. Any code that's between `<%` and `%>` gets executed, and the rest simply gets written to the browser. That means that your JavaScript will not get read by the JSP interpreter, and the server will simply add the bookmark.

What you are looking for is a request to the server to actually add the bookmark. Something like `mypage.jsp?addBookmark=true` which adds the bookmark.

Comment: okay, that makes sense.  So is there a way to fix this?  I'd rather not have to resort to forms and servlets.  I want to keep it simple

Answer (score 3):

JSP is executed when your page is loaded as all commands in JSP are executed on your server.
Javascript instead is only executed in the browser.

So what you are seeing is the server is building the page, executing the function and then outputting the page. 
The functionality is not inside your javascript anymore. At least not if it's not outputting some javascript code itself.

When you click the button, the jsp code already executed. If you want to execute the code in that moment you will need to write it in javascript instead of jsp or call it using another request.